# How to change default allocated camera to back facing camera in csipsimple?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am developing an Android application of a field service support and using CSipSimple for that.
I want to use the back-facing camera only because there is no need for the front camera in my app.
The problem is that the app allocates the front camera by default.
I am a fresher and not familiar with ndk.
Can anyone tell me how to set the default allocated camera to front camera?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can change the "Default" camera, or why you would want t really. When you launch your camera activity you can check against CameraInfo for which integer is the back facing camera and then from there you can open the camera with it. Kind of like this:

```
int backCamera = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
Camera mCamera = Camera.open(backCamera);
```

This wont change the "Default" exactly, but will open up the camera with the back facing lens as opposed to the front.

Or you can do this exact thing but with the front facing camera via

```
int frontCamera = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
```

Sorry, I am not sure which camera you actually wanted from your above question.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.
In My application, there has to be two devices. Remote device and server device. the camera view of the remote device should be streaming in server device. when i  changed camera of the remote device to back facing, the streaming view of the server device is showing rotated to 180 angle.

but when i allocate front facing camera(or which is by default allocated in csipsimple app) the streaming view shows normal.

If i run the application in device with no front camera the streaming view in normal also. Check this out https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple